# Copy files between two remote locations

Tags: linux

I work in computer "A", and I have files in computer "B" that I want to copy to a folder in the network, "C". "A" and "B" are part of the LAN network.

Now, I'm doing something like this:

I have mounted (for another reason) the folders I want to copy in "B" to "A", and then I copy to "C".

I'm wondering if this is slower or not than ssh to "B" and copy to "C".

Any idea?

Comment: How did you mount "B" files on "A" ? NFS? Or are the files on a NAS or SAN accessible by both "A" and "B"?

Comment: I mounted by the folders by sshfs. The files are located in the local partition of "B". "C" is a location in the main server.

Comment: sshfs is just slow ... look for better ways like NFS or maybe just a gz-compressed pipe using tar and ssh (for large amounts of data).

Answer (score 0):

A, B and C are "independent" computers ... ?

If B is mounted to A and you execute the copy command on A, it's basically twice the traffic on the network. So yes, copying from B to C is much faster.

Comment: true, but since I would have to ssh from A to B, I wanted to know if the traffic would go through A anyway...

Comment: If you ssh from A to B, no, you logged into B - all commands are executed there. The traffic would not hit A in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use rsync to copy the files. It'll only transfer the parts of the file which have changed and it uses compression by default. So if you copy files over a low bandwidth link, just try to deduplicate and compress. It doesn't matter from where you copy the files if you use the same link from different endpoints.